# How can I edit a collection of filenames in a property grid?

Tags: c#, collections, propertygrid

I have a collection of filenames in a C# class:

```
    private List<string> m_files

    public List<string> Files
    {
        get
        {
            return m_files;
        }
        set
        {
            m_files = value;
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to display and edit this collection in a property grid, specifically I would like to be able to add files to this collection with a standard `FileDialog`. Which is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hijack the StringCollectionEditor for a cheap solution:

```
    [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public List<string> Files {
        get { return m_files; }
        set { m_files = value; }
    }
```

But actually checking the files or using an OFD is going to require you writing your own UITypeEditor.  Do keep in mind that the *paths* of the files at design time is in no way representative for the paths they'll have when you deploy your project.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`EditorAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute.aspx) to specify that this property is edited with a [`CollectionEditor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor.aspx):

```
private List<string> m_files

[EditorAttribute(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public List<string> Files
{
    get
    {
        return m_files;
    }
    set
    {
        m_files = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to connect a `FileDialog` to the CollectionEditor?

Comment: Create a custom CollectionEditor http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/propertygridcollection.aspx

Comment: This code doesn't work, a TypeConverter would be required to use CollectionEditor.